# Why is my finger deforming so weirdly and not following the bones?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have copy rotation from the parent bones, and when I rotate the first bone of one finger, the bones don't follow along 100%, and the mesh deforms horribly.

I think it's something with weight paint, but I can't figure out why this is happening. I've attached the blend file.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: did my answer helped you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, this is part of a bigger mesh/armature, so I can't do automatic weighting of it or I will break other parts, but this will help me set up the weights manually in a correct way! Unless there is a way to do Automatic Weighting with just a part of the mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this:

1. Select your armature in Object Mode
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and `Apply Location`
3. Select your mesh then keep holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select your armature
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and `Parent with Automatic Weighting`

This will fix your problem as shown below:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]